Parser issue in libxml2
I am facing issue
I am trying to replace Xerces-C with libxml2, but when I parse my data in my application, it returns:

SAX Exception: Error while parsing via xmlParseChunk, parseStatus = 5

parserCtx = xmlCreatePushParserCtxt(&sax_name_Handler, parser, NULL, 0, NULL);
int parseStatus = xmlParseChunk(parserCtx, xml, strlen(xml),0);

I tried
parserCtx = xmlCreatePushParserCtxt(&sax_name_Handler, Null, NULL, 0, NULL);

but got this

SAX exception: Error while parsing via xmlParseChunk, parseStatus=1 in message:


Does that happen with all XML input? Or just specific data? This question would be easier to answer with a [mcve] -- can you provide us with runnable example code and a sample XML document that triggers that error?
